# Is there a way to specify a top margin for all headers except the top header?

Tags: css

I would like to have extra space before a header in the middle of my
document but not the first header at the top of the page.

That seems like it would be a common situation but I have to
manually specify it.

In other words. I want this

[image]

but if I specify

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 1.83em;
}
```

Then I get this ugly extra space at the top

[image]

I get that I can fix it by manually specifying the top header. For example

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 1.83em;
}
h1:first-child {
  margin-top: 0.66em;
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is some other way(s) and what the tradeoffs are. I can certainly add a class or an id to the first header and change the CSS to use that class or header but I'm assuming this is a common pattern so I'm wondering if there are common solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:not` pseudo class to define the style for all `h1`, but the first:

```css
h1:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 1.83em;
}
```

```html
<h1>first</h1>

<h1>second</h1>

<h1>third</h1>
```